# How to add background blur when inspecting an object?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to add background blur when inspecting an object, I watched a lot of videos on the topic, but no one did blur, and if they did, they added the object to the widget.

I want something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you set up a camera for the inspected item with specific exposure and focus settings that could work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).